# Footer will adjust when the body expands

Tags: html, footer, sticky-footer

My CSS:

```
.footer {
    position: absolute;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    color: #FFF;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

This is my code for my footer.
**I have no idea why it doesn't appear on my screen.**

Comment: Share your working HTML code as well

Comment: `<footer>
            <div class="container">
                <p class="footer-text">&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year </p>
            </div>
        </footer>`
**this is my HTML code, is something wrong with it? thanks!**

Comment: buddy, HTML code means, everything.. not only the footer tag.! Create a Fiddle or a snippet feature from Stackoverflow